# strcoll() expects parameter 1 to be string in uasort()

Tags: php, locale

I need to sort an array that contains strings from different languages. The best way I found is the following:

```
setlocale(LC_COLLATE, 'tr_TR.utf8'); // or any other locale I use.
uasort($aInput['values'],'strcoll');
```

Even though uasort works perfectly, it has problems with integers and shows the warning:

> strcoll() expects parameter 1 to be string

Should I be loop the whole array and cast integer values to string before calling uasort or is there any other way?

Comment: what does your array look like, is there arrays inside array?

Comment: Yes the arrays are inside the array.

Comment: so that explains the problem, do you expect to sort a multi-dimensional array?

Comment: Well sometimes it is multi-dimensional, sometimes it is not. This is a modification to a social platform's code.

Comment: try the code i posted below see if it works for you

Answer (score 1):

You can try to sort it multi-dimensional using locale settings.

```
array_multisort($aInput['values'], SORT_LOCALE_STRING);
```

Comment: Well it turns out that this function break my site. I guess it messes up the values associated in the array :-(

Comment: you can write your own sort function then